# close the custom inputdialog on clicking a button in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I have created a custom search dialog with few input fields and two buttons such as "Submit" and "Close". On pressing close I want to close the dialog window and get back to parent window, and similarly on submit I could filter the data and dialog box remains active, In both the scenarios I want to close the dialog window, How do I do that, Please help.......

Sample Main Window

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from search_dialog import Ui_Dialog
import sys

class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 150, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.open_dialog)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))

    def open_dialog(self):

        dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog(self.centralwidget)
        ui = Ui_Dialog()
        ui.setupUi(dialog)
        dialog.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Search Dialog

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(508, 230)
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Dialog)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 60, 436, 19))
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.widget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.radioButton = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.widget)
        self.radioButton.setObjectName("radioButton")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.radioButton)
        self.radioButton_2 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.widget)
        self.radioButton_2.setObjectName("radioButton_2")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.radioButton_2)
        self.radioButton_3 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.widget)
        self.radioButton_3.setObjectName("radioButton_3")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.radioButton_3)
        self.radioButton_4 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.widget)
        self.radioButton_4.setObjectName("radioButton_4")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.radioButton_4)
        self.radioButton_5 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.widget)
        self.radioButton_5.setObjectName("radioButton_5")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.radioButton_5)
        self.widget1 = QtWidgets.QWidget(Dialog)
        self.widget1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 160, 158, 25))
        self.widget1.setObjectName("widget1")
        self.horizontalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.widget1)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_3")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget1)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget1)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.widget2 = QtWidgets.QWidget(Dialog)
        self.widget2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(71, 111, 371, 22))
        self.widget2.setObjectName("widget2")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.widget2)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget2)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget2)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.lineEdit)

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.radioButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Column 1"))
        self.radioButton_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Column 2"))
        self.radioButton_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Column 3"))
        self.radioButton_4.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Column 4"))
        self.radioButton_5.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Column 5"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Cancel"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Submit"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Enter the string : "))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to connect your button to the slots `QDialog::reject()` and `QDialog::accept()`.

You can do it in your method `setupUi`:

```
class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
...
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(Dialog.reject)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(Dialog.accept)
```

You can also use `QDialog::exec()` instead of `QDialog::show` to make your dialog modal and get directly the result when it is closed.